# Textfield to pop out a keyboard which contains the phone keypad/numbers only

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have created a textfield as follows;

```
{
  xtype:'textfield',
  name:'telephone',
  label:'Telephone'
}
```

Instead of popping up the default keyboard which has characters and numbers. I need the keyboard to only display the phone keypad (Only numbers). Since the textfield is about getting the phone number of the user, there's no point displaying a keyboard with characters.

Comment: None of these solutions appear to work in Ionic 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using `numberfield` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using property component of textfield:

```
{
  xtype:'textfield',
  component: {
    xtype: 'input',
    type: 'tel'
  },
  name:'telephone',
  label:'Telephone'
}
```

You also have other standard input types: email, search, date... see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Answer (score 0):

This work for me in HTML5.

```
<input type="tel" height=30px width=200px></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend `Ext.ActionSheet` and add button 0-9 as item in it and call `show()` method on focus of textfield and on buttons tap event concat value of textfield.

I use this method it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number"/>
```

This works for me in Android