# Show only number keyboard on Ionic/Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard, ionic-framework, numeric-input

I have two problems in my Ionic/Cordova app, both with numeric keyboard that I not have option to show it.

1) Password input that needs to show a numeric keyboard. It's showing a alpha numerical keyboard. If I change to numeric, I can't hide the entries (with *).

2) Numeric input that I have to insert currency mask (left to right). All options that I find runs in text input.

Anybody help me? Please!

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/10481949/4548981

Comment: If I add type="number" numeric keyboard shows correctly, but data don't hide (like ****). If I add type="password" the data hides, but the keyboard not shows only numeric.

Comment: It's just not possible, the password type shows a regular keyboard and you can't change that

Comment: How did you solved the second issue?

Comment: None of these solutions work in Ionic 3

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I resolved with CSS:

```
<input type="number" style="-webkit-text-security:disc">
```

Thanks all for help!

Answer (score 19):

I resolved with tel:

```
<input type="tel">
```

Comment: It can't hide the entries (with *) read the question carefully before answering

Answer (score 6):

I am using
`<ion-input type="number" pattern="\d*"></ion-input>`
and it is working

[android keypad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62GKy.png)

Answer (score 5):

2) Numeric input that I have to insert currency mask (left to right). All options that I find runs in text input.

Using http://www.numbox.org you can solve the second issue.

Answer (score 5):

Old but i just had this problem.

I solved it making the input:

```
  type="number"
  pattern="[0-9]*"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use pattern attribute:
`<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*">`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your input, onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'

Comment: Thanks, but it not work... I need show only the numeric keyboard on enter in password input

Comment: @WillianCustódio Any luck?